# Where the .env keys get stored after the nom build command in react?

Tags: reactjs, django, webpack, environment-variables

Hello guys I build a react application using Django as the backend and having many keys at.env file. Now when I build the react app with the ‘npm run build’ command it builds the index file with CSS in the build folder. But where it stores all the keys of the .env file which were used in some components. Or its gets build with all the components

Comment: are you using create-react-app ?

Answer (score 0):

On a client-rendered application (like a standard React app), the build process will embed the actual environment variable values in your bundled code, making it available when serving the build to a hosting server.

[Reference from the "Create React App" documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)

> WARNING: Do not store any secrets (such as private API keys) in your React app!

> Environment variables are embedded into the build, meaning anyone can
> view them by inspecting your app's files.

Comment: What is the best way to store API keys and stuff

Answer (score 0):

when you run `npm run build`  The environment variables are embedded and you can read them at runtime. by  loading  HTML into memory on the server and replacing  placeholders in runtime . check [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables) for more information